# Why Can't I Install Visual Studio 2015 CTP On A Production Machine?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

On the Visual Studio 15 CTP [download page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-ctp-vs.aspx), it says this:

> This release is unsupported and are not intended for use on production computers, or to create production code. We strongly recommend only installing this release in a virtual machine, or on a computer that is available for reformatting.

So... why can't I install it on a production machine? I'm not talking about creating production code (obviously not that!). But I can't even install it?

Is this because all pre-release software tends to come with the "it might explode your PC" caveat? Or is there something more to it, like the new compiler is just unable to live side-by-side with the old one from VS 2013?

Comment: It's because it's still in development and things change rapidly. The way something behaves in either the compiler, or the IDE could change between CTP versions.

Comment: It's just a warning that it's not a 'go-live' license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "we strongly recommended only installing this release in a VM, or on a computer that is available for reformatting" warning falls into the "it might explode your PC" bucket.  However, that said, this release does not have a Go-Live license (which is different).

**What is this Go-Live thing?**

The license terms for Visual Studio pre-releases come in 2 buckets - Go-Live and, well, not Go-Live.  The terms for a Go-Live license are basically the same as the released product: some amount of support (though not the full MS 10-year support policy), and no specific restrictions on what you do with your projects created with that prerelease build.  Go-Live licenses are generally used for the RC releases that come shortly before general availability (aka RTM).

However, a non Go-Live license (such as [the one applicable in this case](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/legal/dn763936)) has the following clauses (emphasis added):

> INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS.
>
> •You may install and use any number of copies of the software solely for evaluation purposes to design, develop and test your programs. If you use the software on Microsoft Azure, additional charges and terms may apply.
>
> •**You may not deploy or distribute any program you design or develop with the software**, except that you may deploy your programs internally solely to evaluate any deployment technologies contained in the software.
>
> •**You may not test the software in a live operating environment or public website unless Microsoft permits you to do so under another agreement**.

Based on these restrictions, the recommendation is more strong that you don't install these on a production machine as it is solely intended for evaluation purposes.